# get the year from the give string of date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have this date format

> Jan 1, 2015

how can i get the year "2015" from the string "Jan 1, 2015"?

so far I tried this

```
var str = "Jan 1, 2015";
var res = str.substr(1, 7);
```

but unfortunately and sadly not working. Any help, ideas, clues please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be the most safe solution:

```
new Date('Jan 1, 2015').getFullYear();  // 2015
```

Comment: To be honest, this is the only proper solution, so far.

Comment: Not it is **not** safe. The date is not in a standard format.

Comment: @SalmanA Well, it depends on the standard you are talking about. This can work as `MMM d, YYYY`: rather common way of displaying the date.

Comment: @SalmanA However! I just found that this date format is kinda standard: [RFC2822](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3) and is used as [example in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Examples).

Answer (score 1):

You can explode string with `,` delimiter:

```
var res = +'Jan 1, 2015'.split(',')[1];
```

or with `substr`:

```
var res = +'Jan 1, 2015'.substr(7),
    res = +'Jan 1, 2015'.substr(-4);
```

Comment: I'd go with `-4` over `7`, seems safer.

Comment: To be blunt, that's not an explanation. That's showing what it does.

Comment: @hsz you have forgotten this way : `res = +'Jan 1, 2015'.slice(-4)`

Answer (score 1):

If the string is *always* in that format, this is an option:

```js
var str = "Jan 1, 2015";
var year = parseInt(str.split(', ').pop());
alert(year)
```

`str.split(', ')` splits the string up into an array like this: `["Jan 1", "2015"]`
Then, `.pop` returns the last value, `"2015"`, and `parseInt` obviously parses that as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use one of the most complicate way !

```
    O O
     °
    \O/
```

- it valid only **string** *NOT* **date** from year 0 to 3999.
  `Feb 31, 2015` is a valid String not a valid Date

```js
var reg = /^([JFMASON][abceglnoprtuv]{2}) ([1-9]|[12][0-9]|[3][01]), ([0-9]|[12][0-9]|[123]?[0-9][0-9]{2})$/;

var r;
document.write('<br> :' +  ( (r = 'Feb 31, 2015'.match(reg))  ? r[3] : 'not valid') );
document.write('<br> :' +  ( (r = 'Jan 31, 3015'.match(reg))  ? r[3] : 'not valid') );
document.write('<br> :' +  ( (r = 'Jan 31, 2015'.match(reg))  ? r[3] : 'not valid') );
document.write('<br> :' +  ( (r = 'Jan 31, 1995'.match(reg))  ? r[3] : 'not valid') );
document.write('<br> :' +  ( (r = 'Jan 31, 115'.match(reg))  ? r[3] : 'not valid') );
document.write('<br> :' +  ( (r = 'Jan 31, 15'.match(reg))  ? r[3] : 'not valid') );
document.write('<br> :' +  ( (r = 'Jan 31, 5'.match(reg))  ? r[3] : 'not valid') );
document.write('<br> :' +  ( (r = 'Jan 31, 0'.match(reg))  ? r[3] : 'not valid') );

document.write('<br> :' +  ( (r = 'Jan 31, 4000'.match(reg))  ? r[3] : 'not valid') );
```

Comment: Replace: `[anebarprayunulugepctov]` with `[abceglnoprtuv]`. You don't need duplicates in chartacter classes.

Answer (score 0):

All the other solutions are just manipulating the string. But if it is really a date:

```
var year = new Date("Jan 1, 2015").getFullYear();
//year = 2015
```

Comment: No need for `Date.parse`. `Date` constructor works like `Date.parse`. (not a downvoter)

Comment: Now it's edited, it's merely a duplicate of VisionN's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the javaScript Date format:

```
var date = new Date(str);
var year = date.getFullYear();
```

For more infos look at 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Don't use w3schools as a reference, use [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) instead. This answer is also a duplicate of VisioN's

Comment: Why should I use mdn instead?

Comment: More accurate, complete documentation. w3schools is extremely lacking in that aspect, not to mention they're trying way to hard to make it seem like they're affiliated with w3c, while they're not.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse("Jan 1, 2015");
console.log(timestamp);        //1420052400000
```

and convert any type of date params

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = 'Jan 1, 2015';
var data1 = data.split(' ');
alert(data1[2]);
```

Split the value then get the last.
In your example split in space and get the last index which is 2

you can also use pop()

`data1.pop()`